# Place object to a wall from the start of the scene with Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm developing a scene un Unity 2017 with the Mixed Reality tool kit for Hololens and I want to place all my objects in different parts of the wall or floor since the start of the scene.

I already know how to use tap to place objects in the environment but I want it to analyze the space and place the objects on walls or floor depending of the shape of the room.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go look at the [Spacial Understanding](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit/wiki/HoloToolkit.SpatialUnderstanding) parts of the [MixedRealityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit) (there's a Unity package download linked in the README).

I only played with it briefly, as it wasn't suitable for the project I was working on, but there are some easily locatable [getting started](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/2364/getting-started-with-holotoolkit) resources.

The package allows the device to scan a fixed volume space (let the user decide what portions of their surroundings to use for the application), as a developer you can dictate the minimum volume size that your application needs. After scanning a number of query functions become available as the Spacial Understanding starts analyzing the scanned area, allowing you as a developer to find platforms, walls, floors, etc. so that you can place objects in the appropriate places:

> The below object placement query is looking for a place to put a half meter cube on the edge of a surface, away from other previously place objects and near the center of the room.

```
List<ObjectPlacementRule> rules = 
    new List<ObjectPlacementRule>() {
        ObjectPlacementRule.Create_AwayFromOtherObjects(1.0f),
    };

List<ObjectPlacementConstraint> constraints = 
    new List<ObjectPlacementConstraint> {
        ObjectPlacementConstraint.Create_NearCenter(),
    };

Solver_PlaceObject(
    “MyCustomObject”,
    new ObjectPlacementDefinition.Create_OnEdge(
        new Vector3(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f), 
        new Vector3(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f)),
    rules.Count,
    UnderstandingDLL.PinObject(rules.ToArray()),
    constraints.Count,
    UnderstandingDLL.PinObject(constraints.ToArray()),
    UnderstandingDLL.GetStaticObjectPlacementResultPtr());
```

> If successful, a “ObjectPlacementResult” structure containing the placement position, dimensions and orientation is returned. In addition, the placement is added to the dll’s internal list of placed objects. Subsequent placement queries will take this object into account. The “LevelSolver.cs” file in the Unity sample contains more example queries.

[image: Successful placement using Spacial Understanding]